# Transform exponential expression into log / find solution to: $y = (a - x_1)^\gamma + (a - x_2)^\gamma$

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, exponential-function

I need to find the solution to the expression $y = (a - x_1)^\gamma + (a - x_2)^\gamma$ for $a$, but have problems with exponential, where $\gamma $ can be greater than 0 and smaller than 1 or greater than 1: (1) $0 < \gamma < 1$ and (2) $\gamma > 1$. I think $(a - x_1)^\gamma$ has to be to transformed into logarithm, but I can't find the way to solve it. I would appreciate any hint or help.

Comment: But log of sum isn't sum of logs...

Comment: what is the unknown here? Is it just $\gamma$?

Comment: I need to solve it for $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can assume $a>x_1>x_2$, which is ok if $x_1-x_2<y^{1/\gamma}$, then $a$ is between $x_1$ and $y^{1/\gamma}+x_2$.  You can then try the Bisection method to home in on the answer.

Comment: Sorry for my low level of math and maybe a stupid question, but so we can elevate the expression $y = (a - x_1)^\gamma + (a - x_2)^\gamma$ by $\frac{1}{\gamma}$ and get $y^{\frac{1}{\gamma}} = (a - x_1) + (a - x_2)$?

Comment: No. But when $a=x_2+y^{1/\gamma}$, the right-hand side is more than $(a-x_2)^\gamma=(y^{1/\gamma})^\gamma=y$